# Is there a way to use materializecss with Gatsby js?

Tags: materialize, gatsby

when I use the materialize css you have to use some of their javascript functions to get the CSS to work right

```
  componentDidMount() {
    //sidenav
    const sideNav = document.querySelector('.sidenav')
    const instance = M.Sidenav.init(sideNav, {})
  }
```

These component use the window in gatsby js. Gatsby js won't allow that. has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby is based on React and it's usually advised against manipulating the main dom when coding in React. Instead you should try to use [references](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) or look for a [react variant](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/) of the library you want to use that has been adapted.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a materialize-css component with:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  require('materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js')
}

class Navigation extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav')
    window.M.Sidenav.init(elem, {})
}
```

You can probably also use dynamic imports I think.

I still haven't understood how to make materialize waves.js effects work though.